# What do variadic functions get compiled to?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, variadic

In Java, variadic methods are re-written by the compiler so that they become methods that take an array where the variadic arguments are expected (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168342/is-a-variable-length-argument-treated-as-an-array-in-java)).

What happens in Scala?

My main concern is whether the variadic arguments are implicitly copied to an `Array` if another type of collection is passed or not, i.e. would the compiler somehow re-write this snippet:

```
val strings = Seq("hello")
"%s".format(strings: _*)
```

to the following?

```
val strings = Seq("hello")
"%s".format(strings.toArray: _*)
```

As a follow-up question: are there differences whether the variadic method implements a Java interface or if it's pure Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this out pretty easily with `javap -v`. If you compile the following code (using `String.format` instead of `"%s".format` for now) with 2.12:

```
class Example1 {
  val strings = Seq("foo")
  def formatResult = String.format("%s", strings: _*)
}
```

You'll get this:

```
  public java.lang.String formatResult();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: ldc           #21                 // String %s
         2: aload_0
         3: invokevirtual #23                 // Method strings:()Lscala/collection/Seq;
         6: getstatic     #29                 // Field scala/reflect/ClassTag$.MODULE$:Lscala/reflect/ClassTag$;
         9: ldc           #31                 // class java/lang/String
        11: invokevirtual #35                 // Method scala/reflect/ClassTag$.apply:(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;
        14: invokeinterface #41,  2           // InterfaceMethod scala/collection/Seq.toArray:(Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        19: checkcast     #43                 // class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
        22: invokestatic  #47                 // Method java/lang/String.format:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
        25: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      26     0  this   LExample1;
```

So yep, it'll convert `strings` to an array.

If you use `"%s".format`, though, like this:

```
class Example2 {
  val strings = Seq("foo")
  def formatResult = "%s".format(strings: _*)
}
```

You won't see the conversion:

```
  public java.lang.String formatResult();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #21                 // class scala/collection/immutable/StringOps
         3: dup
         4: getstatic     #27                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
         7: ldc           #29                 // String %s
         9: invokevirtual #33                 // Method scala/Predef$.augmentString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        12: invokespecial #37                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        15: aload_0
        16: invokevirtual #39                 // Method strings:()Lscala/collection/Seq;
        19: invokevirtual #43                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.format:(Lscala/collection/Seq;)Ljava/lang/String;
        22: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 14: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      23     0  this   LExample2;
```

This is because the Scala compiler's encoding of varargs is different from the Java compiler's (which of course knows nothing about Scala's `Seq`). You can force the Scala compiler to generate Java-compatible varargs methods with the `@varargs` annotation:

```
class Example3 {
  def foo(xs: String*): Unit = ()

  @annotation.varargs
  def bar(xs: String*): Unit = ()

  val strings = Seq("foo")
  def fooResult = foo(strings: _*)
  def barResult = bar(strings: _*)
}
```

Note that this generates *both* encodings, though, so `bar(strings: _*)` still won't involve an array conversion, since the Scala compiler in that case chooses the Scala-encoded method.

So to sum up: calling Java varargs methods from Scala with `seq: _*` will always involve `toArray` getting called on the `Seq`, while this won't happen when calling Scala varargs methods from Scala (whether or not they're annotated with `@varargs` for Java compatibility).

Comment: as an addition to the (excellent) answer, note that in Scala 2.13 varargs will use `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` instead of `scala.collection.Seq`. See https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/591and http://eed3si9n.com/masking-scala-seq